# How to read advertising data from BLE Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

Advertising data is in readable format for iPhone, but it is in decimal format for android. How to read and interpret the advertising packet for android.

```
 this.scanner = this.ble.scan(["00EDSE-0000-00AE-9VVQ-9125475145125"], 1).subscribe((response) => {
              console.log("success scan.." + JSON.stringify(response));
              this.ble.connect(response.id).subscribe((response) => {
                this.toast.show("Successfully paired", '2000', 'bottom').subscribe((toast) => {
                  console.log(toast);
                  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Android advertising data is received as an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer). You need to convert it to a human readable string using javascripts `String.fromCharCode` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

```
let stringResult = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
```

Where `buffer` is the `advertising` property of you `response` object. You can find the ionic-native docs for BLE [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/).